# 'Type' is a variable but is used like a Type error with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method like this:

```
private static void OfElementType2(Type elementType, Type baseType)
{
    var baseCollection = new FilteredElementCollector(DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument)
        .OfClass(baseType);

    var derivedCollection = (from e in baseCollection.ToElements()
        where e is elementType select e as elementType);
}
```

I am getting the

> 'Type' is a variable but is used like a Type

exception at `where e is elementType` and again at `select e as elementType`. Can someone explain this concept to me?

Doing `typeof(elementType)` doesn't do what I thought it would. What am I missing?

**edit**

Apologies for the missing context. The problem that I have is that there is a class-based selector that I can use `FilteredElementColector().OfClass()` but it has certain derived classes limitations. So basically if I have a class `Room`, it won't work on it because it's derived from `SpatialElement` class. In that case, I need to use `SpatialElement` class and check if it is of type `Room` so that I can isolate only `Room` objects (there are other classes that inherit from `SpatialElement`). There are a handful of these exceptions that I have to work around so that's why I have this question. I was able to solve it like so:

```
private static IList<Element> OfElementType2(Type elementType)
{
    return new FilteredElementCollector(DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument)
        .OfClass(elementType.BaseType)
        .Where(x => x.GetType() == elementType)
        .Select(x => ElementSelector.ByElementId(x.Id.IntegerValue))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: [Type.IsSubclassOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Type.IsAssignableFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: We already have plenty of questions on Stack Overflow discussing how to do runtime checks based on instances of `Type`. In the `is` and `as` operators, you _must_ provide an actual type name as the second operand, not a variable. Without a good [mcve] clearly illustrating your scenario, it's impossible to know what the best answer is for you, but one likely option that would be too is to change the method to be generic, as in `void OfElementType2<TElement, TBase>()`, where the caller provides actual types known at compile time. Then you could use `TElement` and `TBase` as types like you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho your answer gave me an idea, and I was able to solve the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to test against a concrete type, not a variable (even if that variable is of type `Type`) this will not work in this form. However if you know the type, example: `Room` or `SpatialEvent` you can test against that.

See sample:

```
var derivedRoomCollection = baseCollection.ToElements().Where(t => t is Room)
var derivedSpatialEventCollection = baseCollection.ToElements().Where(t => t is SpatialEvent)
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically stating the identifier `elementType` is not an *actual* type, you'll need to replace it with the *concrete* type.

Comment: What if I don't know what that is until runtime. Can I convert variable type to Type?